# Does the Backfire chance of the Devil Axe reset on promotion in Fire Emblem: Binding Blade?

Tags: fire-emblem-binding-blade

In Fire Emblem: Binding Blade, the Devil Axe has a (21% minus [level]) chance to backfire.

Meaning, that if it's used by a lvl 20 Fighter, he has a 1% chance for the axe to backfire.

Does that reset if he promotes?

Will it have a 20% chance to backfire if he uses it now that he's a lvl 1 Warrior, or will it be a 0% chance due to him effectively being a lvl 21 unit?

Comment: I can’t say for Binding Blade, but at least for the FE games I’ve played, class and level are separate things. While a lv1 warrior is essentially a lv21 fighter, it’s still a lv1 (promoted) unit.

Comment: so does that mean it has a 20% chance to backfire because he's lvl 1, promoted or not?

Comment: That is what I am thinking. However I've never played Binding Blade and cannot found any resources to back it up.

Comment: old reply, but can you post this as an answer for the sake of completion?